# jQuery function reloads page automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have a problem using jQuery. I've made a drop-down menu and I want it drop-down when li tag inside menu is clicked.

I can use jQuery click function. It works but when jQuery function is completed then the web page automatically reloads and drop-down menu becomes hidden again.

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` to the click handler.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click_nav li a").click(function(){
        $("#slide_nav").show();
    });

This is my jQuery code. Where I can put in this code you provide?
});

Comment: which technology you uses Asp.net, PHP, Java, etc

Comment: Add # in Ancher tag Ex <a href="#">

Comment: Tanjed, we ask that questions are self-contained here, which means that the code you are having trouble with appears in the question itself. Since the question is reliant on that link (and is already 404ing) it no longer makes any sense, and the community is likely to put it on hold. Would you improve the question please?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click_nav li a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // preventDefault() here
        $("#slide_nav").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear Halcyon...

Thanks a lot... This jQuery work what I'm look..

Thanks man... I'm try to give vote in your solution, but I didn't have enough reputation. That's why my vote wasn't show and count publicly. But Thanks a lot again and again and again. Because I'm trying to solve this problem many time ago but I didn't. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML.....

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="testing_menu">
                        <ul id="click_nav">
                            <li><a>Drop-Down</a>
                                <ul id="slide_nav" style="display: block;">
                                    <span class="tri_angle"></span>
                                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Setting</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Log Out</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```